# Passing parameters for external program as string variable

Tags: powershell, parameters

I've a simple command that I need to execute via PowerShell on remote machine.

```
E:\Programs\GMM\bin\GMMFailoverTool.exe -mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=GMM01" list
```

The problem I'm having is executing it properly with PowerShell even without trying to do this via `Invoke-Command`.

```
$binary = "E:\Programs\GMM\bin\GMMFailoverTool.exe"
$command = "-mssql=`"Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01`" list"

Write-Host BINARY: $binary -ForegroundColor Yellow
write-Host ARGS: $command -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host FullCommand: $binary $command -ForegroundColor Yellow
& $binary $command
```

Output:

```
BINARY: E:\Programs\GMM\bin\GMMFailoverTool.exe
ARGS: -mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01" list
FullCommand: E:\Programs\GMM\bin\GMMFailoverTool.exe -mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01" list
```

And the return of the command is like it didn't get any parameters at all (or those were incorrect).

The question is how to properly pass those arguments where `$command` is already defined as it should? If I do it by hand without having it all in variables it works…

```
& "E:\Programs\GMM\bin\GMMFailoverTool.exe" -mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01" list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments as an array:

```
$command = '-mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01"', 'list'
& $binary $command
```

Also, I had some situations where the only way of correctly passing arguments to an external program was to run the command with `cmd.exe`:

```
$command = '-mssql="Server=SomeServer;Database=gmm01" list'
cmd /c "$binary $command"
```

To run the command remotely you need to either define the variables inside the scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer 'remotehost.example.com' -ScriptBlock {
  $binary  = ...
  $command = ...
  & $binary $command
}
```

or (perhaps better, if the value of `$command` is generated by some other function) pass them into the scriptblock via the parameter `-ArgumentList`:

```
$binary  = ...
$command = ...

Invoke-Command -Computer 'remotehost.example.com' -ScriptBlock {
  & $args[0] $args[1]
} -ArgumentList $binary, $command
```

because the content of the scriptblock doesn't know anything about the rest of your script.

Comment: When trying & $binary --% $command the output is GMMFailoverTool.exe : Unknown options: $command so it seems like it tries to take it directly. Array approach doesn't change anything either.

Comment: *\*slaps self\** Sorry, my mistake. Of course `--%` won't work, because it's supposed to treat everything after as a literal string. See updated answer.

Comment: It works only with Array approach. For both approaches. CMD and the other one. I just had conversion in other part of the code where the return was Array and forcing it into the string.

Comment: Is there any way to give it "RUN PATH"  ? as in go into directory and then execute it?

Comment: Also if i copy the code into Invoke-Command it doesn't work. Is there anything special I should be doing ? except making sure it's an array?

Comment: That depends on *what* you're doing. And how exactly that "doesn't work". Also, what "conversion" and what "other part of the code" are you talking about? Please do not move or expand the target. Focus on getting what you posted to work.

Comment: To not copy/paste whole code I've tried to limit it to merits. I have little function which takes multiple arguments and throws back a simple oneline $command. There was my mistake where return of function was Array yet I was assigning that by [string] $command = functionToGetValues(). I've fixed that and it started to work for the topic in question. However I then take & $binary $command and move it into Invoke-Command and from the output it behaves like it looses the 1st Array Element and just runs the 2nd. I don't want to expand the target. I can open another question by adding "remotely".

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar That's how I was using it. I can execute & $binary $command just before Invoke-Command and it runs fine then I run your 2nd example of Invoke-Command with remotehost.example.com being the same server name as i am executing the script on and the output is diffrent. That's what I don't understand. The only thing I am thinking here is the problem is when I run it locally it takes username/password from Single-SignOn and for some reason Invoke-Command doesn't do that and the external command doesn't  pass user and password

Comment: GMMFailoverTool.exe -mssql="Server=DBSERVER; Database=gmmdb1" -user=dba -password=pw list is the full command... however if you run it without -user -password switch it takes your current logged in credentials. So the question would be if Invoke-Command somehow doesn't do that, and that's why it fails.